# How to refresh reusable cells in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I am building a custom cell in the storyboard with the identifier "TextCell". It is a plane cell, however by code i am adding to each cell a textfield because i can have an "n" number of cells so the user can insert text in each. My issue is that the textfields that i create seem to be creating themselves over and over again in top of the other. I can say this because i have a placeholder text and it gets darker and darker.

I am using ARC as well. Please any insight that you can provide me can help me a lot.

I am attaching the code of the function where i am adding the textfields to the cells:

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TextCell"];


//create text field inside cell and init it with the default settings
UITextField * textHolder = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 10, 300, 44)];
[textHolder setPlaceholder:[cellsText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
//[textHolder setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
[textHolder setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Regular" size:16]];
[textHolder setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[textHolder setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
textHolder.tag = FIELD_PREFIX + indexPath.row;
[textHolder setDelegate:self];

[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"accessoryView" owner:self options:nil];
[textHolder setInputAccessoryView:accessoryView];
[cell addSubview:textHolder];    

//set keyboard to type passwords    
[textHolder setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time the cell gets reused you add another `UITextField` to the preexisting set of text fields. You have two options:

1) Put the text field in the custon table view cell in your storyboard instead of creating it manually. By using a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` you can as well assign your text field to a property in your custom subclass. This has the added bonus that you may add a bunch of other things to the cell. You can then access the property instead of creating a new text field.

2) Remove the "old" text field before creating a new one. You'd probably have to search all subviews for instances of `UITextField` to achieve this as you are already using the tag value for something else.

The first one is definitely the cleaner version.

Comment: I am trying the first option and it seems very nice but it creates me some trouble because having the textfield in the storyboard implies that it has an static tag so i can't obtain the current cell by the tag of the textfied when is first responder (This facilitates me the scrolling with the keyboard).                                        The **second** choice it will suit me better but since i am using ARC it is not very clear to me how i can remove the "old" text field. If you can help me with this it will mean a lot. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: On 1: you should be able to link your text field to an `IBOutlet` as long as you use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. When you set that class as your table view cell`s class, you should be able do Command-Drag the text field to your .h file to create the property, no tags needed. You can then handle everything though your subclasses' property. On 2: You need to find the `UITextField` by going through the subviews and remove it form the super view (`removeFromSuperview`). If you have no further references to the text field, it should be deallocated automatically.

Comment: Thanks @TriPhoenix!!! That was it !!!I use the first suggestion and it worked great. I subclassed the cell and created the IBOUTLET there. i use the knowledge in this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) to make the custom subclass but i couldn't have done it without your help.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding the textfield to the view, you should be adding them to the content view:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:textHolder];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks!!! that was part of the problem but it didn't solve it completely, i am a bit of a noob and i was having some issues declaring the cell properly. @NullSleep